# Creating a Controller for DevOps in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a database schema known as BigDataOverview. Most of my Application is already connected to a different schema known as AdminDb.

I also have a .Net Core Application that is well integrated with my AdminDb schema.

My secondary schema has 13 different tables, that are named with numbers as names and a single table that is named "SimpleDataOverview".

I now want to add this secondary schema to my application so that I can `{ get; }` the data to display it in my application.

I have set up my ConnectionString in my **appsettings.json**:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"server=<placeholder>;database=AdminDB;sslmode=none;",
    "OverviewDataConnection": "server=<placeholder>;database=BigDataOverview;sslmode=none;"
}
```

All of the 13 tables that have numbers as names are identical to each other in terms of fields (columns). Therefore I have created a model to match all of them: **NumberTableModel.cs**

```
public class NumberTableModel
{
    [Key]
    public int RowID { get; }

    public int SensorID { get; }
    public DateTime ReadingDate { get; }
    public int ReadingCount { get; }
    public float ApproxDataSize { get; }
    public Time ReadingTime { get; }
    public string JsonData { get; }
    public long LastUpdate { get; }
    public string Source { get; }
}
```

I've also created a DbContext: **DevOpsDbContext**

```
public class DevOpsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DevOpsDbContext(DbContextOptions<DevOpsDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<NumberTableModel> _353224061929963 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NumberTableModel> _353224061929964 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NumberTableModel> _353224061929965 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel>().ToTable("353224061929963");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel>().ToTable("353224061929964");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel>().ToTable("353224061929965");
    }
}
```

And I have set it up in my **Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<DevOpsDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OverviewDataConnection")));
```

[image]

However when I try to create a `Controller` with views, using Entity Framework, Visual Studio will complain with the following Error Message:

[image]

And I believe I do.... I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use one class with multiple table in EF. Maybe it's the source of your error ?
Try to create a parent class and one child by table :

```
public abstract class NumberTableModel
{
    [Key]
    public int RowID { get; }

    public int SensorID { get; }
    public DateTime ReadingDate { get; }
    public int ReadingCount { get; }
    public float ApproxDataSize { get; }
    public Time ReadingTime { get; }
    public string JsonData { get; }
    public long LastUpdate { get; }
    public string Source { get; }
}

public class NumberTableModel1 : NumberTableModel { }

public class NumberTableModel2: NumberTableModel { }

public class NumberTableModel3: NumberTableModel { }
```

And in your `DevOpsDbContext` :

```
public class DevOpsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DevOpsDbContext(DbContextOptions<DevOpsDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<NumberTableModel1> _353224061929963 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NumberTableModel2> _353224061929964 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NumberTableModel3> _353224061929965 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel1>().ToTable("353224061929963");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel2>().ToTable("353224061929964");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NumberTableModel3>().ToTable("353224061929965");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I have time. Thanks! I'll let you know if it fixes the problem.